# A problem in an integration related to Wick rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, wick-rotation, analyticity

In quantum field theory, we often calculate some integrations using Wick rotation. In the following, I will carefully deal with an integration involving Wick rotation. In the end, I have found that I was confused.

The integration is
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int\frac{d^{4}k}{(2\pi)^{4}}\frac{1}{k^{2}+i\epsilon}e^{-ik\cdot x}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{4}}\int d^{3}ke^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_{0}\frac{1}{k_{0}^{2}-(E_{k}-i\epsilon)^{2}}e^{-ik_{0}t}\\
 & \equiv & \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{4}}\int d^{3}ke^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\times\mathrm{I}
\end{eqnarray*}

with
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{I} & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_{0}\frac{1}{k_{0}^{2}-a^{2}}e^{-ik_{0}t}\\
a & = & E_{k}-i\epsilon=\sqrt{m^{2}+\mathbf{k}^{2}}-i\epsilon
\end{eqnarray*}

Now we will use Wick rotation to calculate $\mathrm{I}$. Note that
$\pm a$ are two singularities of the integrand. Consider following
contour. The radii of coutours $l_{5},l_{6}$ are both $R$ and $R\rightarrow\infty$.

[image]

According to contour integral theorem, we can see
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{I} & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_{0}\frac{1}{k_{0}^{2}-a^{2}}e^{-ik_{0}t}\\
 & = & \int_{l_{1}}dz\frac{1}{z^{2}-a^{2}}e^{-izt}+\int_{l_{2}}dz\frac{1}{z^{2}-a^{2}}e^{-izt}\\
 & = & \bigg(\int_{l_{5}}dz\frac{1}{z^{2}-a^{2}}e^{-izt}+\int_{l_{3}}dz\frac{1}{z^{2}-a^{2}}e^{-izt}\bigg)+\bigg(\int_{l_{4}}dz\frac{1}{z^{2}-a^{2}}e^{-izt}+\int_{l_{6}}dz\frac{1}{z^{2}-a^{2}}e^{-izt}\bigg)\\
 &  & \bigg[\text{note: set }z=ik_{E}^{0}\text{ in }l_{3},l_{4}\text{ and combine }l_{5},l_{6}\bigg]\\
 & = & (-i)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_{E}^{0}\frac{1}{(k_{E}^{0})^{2}+a^{2}}e^{tk_{E}^{0}}+\int_{l_{6}}dz\frac{1}{z^{2}-a^{2}}(e^{-izt}+e^{izt}),\ \bigg[\text{set }z=Re^{i\phi}\text{ in }l_{6}\bigg]\\
 & = & (-i)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_{E}^{0}\frac{1}{(k_{E}^{0})^{2}+a^{2}}e^{tk_{E}^{0}}\\
 &  & -iR\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\phi e^{i\phi}\frac{1}{R^{2}e^{2i\phi}-a^{2}}(e^{-itR\cos\phi+tR\sin\phi}+e^{itR\cos\phi-tR\sin\phi})\\
 & \equiv & (-i)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_{E}^{0}\frac{1}{(k_{E}^{0})^{2}+a^{2}}e^{tk_{E}^{0}}+\mathrm{II}
\end{eqnarray*}

with
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{II} & = & -iR\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\phi e^{i\phi}\frac{1}{R^{2}e^{2i\phi}-a^{2}}(e^{-itR\cos\phi+tR\sin\phi}+e^{itR\cos\phi-tR\sin\phi})
\end{eqnarray*}

Actually, I do not know how to prove $\mathrm{II}=0$ as $R\to\infty$.
But if $\mathrm{II}\neq0$ as $R\to\infty$, then we can not simply
obtain
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_{0}\frac{1}{k_{0}^{2}-a^{2}}e^{-ik_{0}t} & = & (-i)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_{E}^{0}\frac{1}{(k_{E}^{0})^{2}+a^{2}}e^{tk_{E}^{0}}
\end{eqnarray*}

So who can prove $\mathrm{II}=0$ or $\mathrm{II}\neq0$ as $R\to\infty$?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Jordans lemma, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma, provides that the integral II goes to 0 as $R\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @CStarAlgebra...Actually, the parameter $t$ in $\mathrm{II}$ can be positive or
negative, so Jordan's lemma may be not suitable in this case.